# The XMLHttpRequest progress event property 'position' is deprecated. Please use 'loaded' instead

Tags: javascript, dojo

Anyone has any idea what this means? Encountered after upgrading Dojo.

Comment: It means the progress event was deprecated from javascript, but Dojo is still using it.

Comment: And what is the progress event? sorry, I'm kinda new to both

Comment: It's the event that fires when progress is made !

Comment: I'm guessing this is due to https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/1.10.2/request/xhr.js#L118 - if you can put together a simple test case and details of what browsers do/don't encounter the issue, I'd suggest filing a bug at https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/

Comment: for future searchers - https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/18544

Comment: Just a note that the property `will be removed in M50, around April 2016.` See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5044837464145920 for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Pulling out [GavinR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2039/gavinr)'s answer, Dojo is relying on the now-deprecated position property of the progress event object. A bug [has been filed](https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/18544) and its progress can be tracked.

Answer (score 0):

Should be fixed in version 1.11 and 1.10.5:
https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/18544